# Pass by value in c++ :Why is the iterable value changing when I'm returning to main function?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, maps

I am trying to print the population the user defines from the current map:

My question is why is the value of the iterable changing when I'm returning it to the main function?

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <string>
     #include <map>

     std::map<std::string , int> :: iterator get_population(std :: string state , std::map<std::string , int> populationMap)
     {
         std::map<std::string , int> :: iterator iter;
         iter = populationMap.find(state);
         // Debug statement
         std::cout << "Population is : " << iter -> second;
         return iter;
     }
     int main()
     {
         std::map<std::string , int> populationMap;

         populationMap.insert({{"Mahrashtra" , 124945748 } , {"Uttar Pradesh" , 223897418} , {"Bihar" , 121741741} , {"West Bengal" , 91276115}});

         std::string state = "";


         std::cout << "Enter the state who's population you want to find : \n";
         std::cin >> state;

         // defining a new iterable which stores return from get_population

         std::map<std::string , int> :: iterator iter;
         iter = get_population(state ,  populationMap);


         std::cout << "The current population of " + state  + " is : ";
         std::cout << iter->second;

     }
```

It gives me the following output :
Enter the state who's population you want to find :
Mahrashtra
Population is : 124945748
The current population of Mahrashtra is : 1769234796

If I pick another key like Bihar it works just fine, it only works differently for Maharashtra. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You pass `populationMap` by value so `iter` in `get_population` is associated with the local copy of `populationMap` and becomes invalid when returned.  Try passing `populationMap` by const reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the map to `get_population` by value.

The lookup happens on the copy of the map, and you're returning an iterator into that copy (which is destroyed when `get_population` returns).

Change your code to look like this:

```
std::map<std::string , int> :: iterator get_population(std :: string state , const std::map<std::string , int> & populationMap)
```

Comment: But then it wouldn't make sense for it to work for bihar right?

Comment: @KhushiRajpal Strictly speaking the code in your question exhibits undefined behaviour due to the use of the invalid iterator.  That being the case, anything can happen -- including it *appearing* to work in certain cases.